# system security error when running Sharepoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard

Tags: 2010, security, configuration-wizard

Background: A few months ago, my company had an issue which resulted in creating a new domain, and migrating all computers and servers to the new domain, including a Sharepoint 2010 installation. At that time, we had the option to edit MS Office documents in the browser (specifically Word and Excel). Since that time, only some Excel files are able to be edited in the browser.

I did some research, and it seems that we need to install Web Apps Server on the Sharepoint server. (although it wasn't installed before, and I'm not sure what the difference is in needing it to open Office files now). I downloaded it and installed it without an issue, but when I ran the configuration wizard, I got an `exception of type System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException` error. The entire log file is at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SeVgAkF7R3cnO3o6h3Ehf9zT1nCUzbt5Jptv6RFj7PA/edit?usp=sharing:

Comment: As part of migration can you check you followed all steps outlined [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao/archive/2011/12/02/sharepoint-migrating-sharepoint-server-from-one-domain-to-another.aspx)

Comment: reboot the server and re-run the config wizard.

Comment: @AmalHashim - I believe it was migrated correctly, as the only thing that's not working as far as I know is the online editing of documents. - e.g. no permissions issues, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- clear configuration cache
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx
- Find current pv value using: 
  `stsadm -o getproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running` 
  if -pv value is yes, change to No. If no change to Yes

  `stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv No`
- re-run configuration wizard:

  `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`
- If still not working, it might need server reboot